# How to check whether url status of a website is online or offline when i click the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, url, web

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    try
        {
            ConnectionId.HostName = "host2.dnswind.com";
            Uri sUrl =new Uri("http://www.chaton.dilipdotnet.com");
            MyWebReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
            MyWebRes = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)MyWebReq.GetResponse();
            sStream = MyWebRes.GetResponseStream();
            string reader = new StreamReader(sStream).ReadToEnd();
            //if (MyWebRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
               WebClient client = new WebClient();
               Stream oStream = MyWebRes.GetResponseStream();
               StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(oStream);
               string sResult = oReader.ReadToEnd();

               if (sUrl.AbsoluteUri.ToString()=true)//here i want to check  
               {
                    MessageBox.Show("connection online");
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Connection offline");
               }
            }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 //Url not valid
                 MessageBox.Show("Sorry you have typed wrong", ex.Message);

            }

         }
```

I want to check whether the user is typed the url it makes online otherwise offline status
for example when I typed the [url](http://www.chatonline.dilipdotnet.com/%22), in winforms the button is clicked it says online if I don't typed it says offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx) or just test [IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) if you don't want to actively ping the internet.  A well-formed URI implies conformance with certain RFCs.  Read more in the  documentation.

```
string strUri = "http://www.microsoft./en-us/default.aspx";
Uri objUri = null;
// Test the URI
if (Uri.TryCreate(strUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out objUri))
{
    // Uri was good.
}
else
{
    // Uri was not good.
}
```

Comment: sir  can you give me an example